# License Plate OCR

Tags: data, computer-vision, ocr

1. Are there any pretrained models or annotated data available for license plate detection?
   I've seen some sets but most of them are little in size. I'm more interested in prod-like quality.
2. Are there any new pretrained models for OCR? Obviously, please don't include tesseract in the answers.
   I've tried it many times, but always got poor results. Preferably, it must be able to read plate numbers from a dashcam.

Kind regards,
Piotr Rarus

Answer (score 1):

Intel OpenVINO is used to optimise inference speed on edge devices. One of their demos was license plate detection. The link can be found here: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2019_R1/_vehicle_license_plate_detection_barrier_0106_description_vehicle_license_plate_detection_barrier_0106.html.

According to the link, it uses MobileNetV2 + SSD-based vehicle and (Chinese) license plate detector.